# change current menu item color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello i have a website with two menus, one on scroll and  another that shows when the header is at top
 i am trying to change the current menu item color when the header is at top

screenshot below
[image]

```
http://skyechopencil.com/home-newest/
```

this is what i have tried but it only affects the menu item when on scroll not when fixed at the top

```
body .container .navigation ul .current-menu-item a {
color: #ff9900 !important;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

can someone help in correctin me

Comment: can you add fiddle here

Comment: body .container .navigation ul .current-menu-item a {
color: #ff9900 !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

Comment: please make your reply an answer so i can vote it, thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the markup with Chrome dev tools on the link you provided and it works fine.

Maybe you are overwriting it somewhere else later down the line.

Try to place your code at the very end of your stylesheet and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

-- language: lang-css -->

```
#sub-header ul li:hover{ background-color: #000;}
#sub-header ul li:hover a{ color: #fff; }
#sub-header ul li.active{ background-color: #000; }
#sub-header ul li.active a{ color: #fff; }
```

```html
<div id="sub-header">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.php">About Us</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```